# ¿Cómo me conecto e inserto desde un archivo PHP local a una base de datos de un hosting?

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart, hosting

Estoy desarrollado una app para Android e iOs, con un registro and login en flutter, PHP y MySQL, tengo una cuenta de 000webhost con mi base de datos y estoy tratando de insertar datos en una tabla a través de un archivo PHP, con los datos que me da la página (BD, usuario y contraseña), **pero el problema es que no sube nada.**

Comparto mi error en consola, la depuración, mi archivo php and mi función de registro en el formulario dart.

Mi archivo de conexión y registro:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','id19*****_root','************','id19*****_databasedb'); 
    //Conectar al hosting
    if (!$db) {
        echo "Database connection failed";
    }

    $cellph = $_POST['celular'];
    $eml = $_POST['correo'];
    $psswd1 = $_POST['passwd'];
    $psswd2 = $_POST['passwd2'];

    $sql = "SELECT celular FROM usuario WHERE celular = '".$cellph."' AND clf = '".$psswd1."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($count == 1) {
        echo json_encode("Error");
    }else{

    if($psswd1 == $psswd2 && strlen($psswd1) >= 8 && strlen($eml) >= 10 && (strlen($cellph) >= 9 && strlen($cellph) <= 15)){

        if (!preg_match('`[a-z]`',$psswd1) || !preg_match('`[A-Z]`',$psswd1) || !preg_match('`[0-9]`',$psswd1)){
            echo json_encode("Contraseña inválida");
         }else{
            $wdps = password_hash($psswd1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $insert = "INSERT INTO usuario(correo,celular,passwd,clf)VALUES('".$eml."','".$cellph."','".$wdps."','".$psswd1."')";
            $query = mysqli_query($db,$insert);
            if ($query) {
                echo json_encode("Success");
            }
         }
    }else{
        echo json_encode("Contraseña inválida");
    }
        
    }

?>
```

Como pueden ver en la línea `$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','id19*****_root','************','id19*****_databasedb');` 
dice localhost, porque en la página de 000webhost me sugiere que coloque eso, pero también lo he intentado con `'https://databases-auth.000webhost.com/'`

Cuando depuro en visual studio code me aparece esto:

````
ArgumentError (Invalid argument (onError): Error handler must accept one object or one object and a stacktrace as arguments.: Closure: (HttpException) => Null)```
````

**Esto sólo ocurre si lo hago intentando conectar con mi BD en webhosting.**

Mientras ejecuto y envío el formulario en Chrome, aparece este error en consola (Solamente cuando intento insertar datos a mi base de datos de webhosting, si subo en una base de datos local en localhost lo hace perfectamente):

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling 
dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

Este error es por un show dialog en la linea 68 de mi archivo registro.dart, pero.... hay una función register() y esta se ejecuta antes que ese show dialog, y lamentablemente no existen nuevos registros dentro de mi tabla "usuario", a menos que lo haga con mi localhost y rut

```
showDialog( context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) { Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () { Navigator.of(context).pop(true); }); return alert; }, );
```

Mi función future async para registro y mi showalertdialog de mi archivo dart:

```
 Future register() async {
    var url =
        "http://192.162.1.137/DataBaseDB/register.php"; //IPv4, colocar después el hosting
    //"https://databases-auth.000webhost.com/"; 
    var response = await http.post(url, body: {
      "correo": correo.text,
      "celular": celular.text,
      "passwd": passwd.text,
      "passwd2": passwd2.text
    });
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    //Comentar abajo
    if (data == "Error") {
      FlutterToast(context).showToast(
          child: Text(
        'User allready exit!',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.red),
      ));
    } else {
      FlutterToast(context).showToast(
          child: Text('Registration Successful',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.green)));
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DashBoard(),
        ),
      );
    }
    //   //return data != "Error";
  }
```

```
showSuccessDialog(BuildContext context) {
  // set up the button
  Widget okButton = TextButton(
    child: Text("OK"),
    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
  );

  // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text(""),
    content: Text("Registro realizado con éxito"),
    actions: [
      okButton,
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop(true); //De aquí es uno de los errores
      });
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

No sé si en mi servidor 000webhosting se admite conexión externa. En mi phpMyAdmin aparece así:

```
Servidor de base de datos
Servidor: Localhost via UNIX socket Tipo de servidor: MariaDB Conexión del servidor: No se está utilizando SSL Documentación Versión del servidor: 10.5.12-MariaDB - MariaDB Server Versión del protocolo: 10 Usuario: id1**********@2a02:****:bad:c0de::14 Conjunto de caracteres del servidor: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Servidor web
Apache
Versión del cliente de base de datos: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 7cc6cc96e675f6d72e5cf0c287f48e167c2abb23 $
extensión PHP: mysqliDocumentación curlDocumentación mbstringDocumentación
Versión de PHP: 7.3.32
    
phpMyAdmin
    Acerca de esta versión: 4.9.5, versión estable más reciente: 5.1.1
```

Espero que alguien me guíe y me ayude a entender que ocurre, porque necesito que la app ingrese registros a la base de datos arriba en webhosting, para continuar haciendo las pruebas, soy principiante en esto, especialmente en flutter. De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Con localhost no te va a funcionar porque eso es para cuando lo haces desde el propio servidor en el que está la base de datos. Con databases-auth.000webhost.com puede que te funcione, pero tienes que ponerlo sin "https://".

Comment: y revisa si el servidor te admite conexion externa. Hay casos de hostings que las bbdd solo se pueden acceder "directamente" desde el localhost, y quizas desde tu equipo donde desarrollas no puedas acceder...

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Muchísimas gracias por la recomendación, no lo sabía, igual probé y no funcionó. Estaba pensando que tal vez es por la función future async y la url del archivo register.php donde está la conexión, quizá deba tener ese archivo subido en el hosting y así funcione.

Comment: @Jakala Muchas gracias por la recomendación. ¿Cómo se comprueba eso? Me aparece al costado: `
    Servidor: Localhost via UNIX socket
    Tipo de servidor: MariaDB
    Conexión del servidor: No se está utilizando SSL Documentación
    Versión del servidor: 10.5.12-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
    Versión del protocolo: 10
    Usuario: id1**********@2a02:****:bad:c0de::14
    Conjunto de caracteres del servidor: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
`  Publicaré el resto en la publicación.

Comment: En tu servidor remoto tienes que programar una API o un Servicio Web para poder modificar/obtener datos de la base de datos desde cualquier cliente (Android, iOS, PC, etc) mediante URL.

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias por tu sugerencia. Investigaré como se podría hacer para mi app.